# Is Ravana Samhita authentic?

Tags: scripture, ravana, samhita

There was a note in the International Ayurvedic Medical Journal that the Sanskrit manuscript of the Ravana Samhita is in the Institute of Oriental Studies of Bhandarkar:

https://fdocuments.in/document/a-review-onravana-samhita-with-specialreference-to-review-onravana-samhita-with

Also, the experts of the Saptarishi Journal of Astrology considered the text of the Ravana Samhita as authentic:

https://www.saptarishisastrology.com//DownloadSection/ArchivedArticles/

However, further nonsense begins.
There are at least three translations of the Ravana Samhita in Hindi, from:

1. Dr. Surkanth Jha
2. Pt. Shivkant Jah
3. Pt. Kisanlal Sharma

• In the astrological part of the translation from the first author there are inclusions or whole fragments of the text from Prashna Marga.

• In the astrological part of the work of the second author there are inclusions or whole fragments of the text from the Brihat Jataka.

• In the astrological part of the translations from all three authors, there is no teaching on the Nakshatra Padas, on which the Saptarishi Journal of Astrology was founded and researched:

https://archive.org/details/Book.AstrolocalityAstrology/1_Ashwini%20Nakshatra%20Padas%20in%20Ravana%20Samhita/

This is very unfortunate and again raises the question of the availability of everything available in these three translations of the text.